# Set a particular browser as "always"

Tags: browser, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean, default-applications

I have Galaxy Nexus with JB. I got stock browser on it and Chrome and I also installed Firefox just to keep it there since I'm a developer and I can test stuff on all three.

But the question I'm having is, what happens if I set a particular browser as "always" when it asks me which one I'd like to use? I keep pressing "just once" because I don't know hot would I change it later if I desire to do so?

1. Is it possible to change/reset this later? How?
2. Does "always" set it as default just for that particular app that's redirecting to browser or does it set OS-wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the default action for an intent is easy enough to do on ICS.

1. From the launcher, press the menu button, and choose `Manage apps`.
2. Select the app that you chose as the default for the action.
3. Scroll down and touch `Clear defaults`.

[image]

Comment: Great! I suppose JB should be no different in this regard?

Comment: I don't see why it would be. This functionality has been in Android since nearly the beginning.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I just booted up the JB emulator and it looks identical there. So go for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can not find an appropriate setting on your device, you may have another app take care for that. There are some on the playstore addressing exactly your problem, e.g.: [DefaultApp Reset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pxlib.android.defaultappset)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsIc4.jpg)</sup> explicitly states *This will work on android 1.5-2.3.3+ & 3.0-3.2+ & 4.0-4.0.3+ & 4.1+*, [Default App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zN2h.jpg)</sup> does not explicitly state (but is free, so you could check).

[image: DefaultApp Reset] [image: Default App Manager]

To your second question: It's rather system-wide for the same action. For example, if you open an audio file from the file manager, and select the player for "always" -- this will also be used if you select an audio file from, say, the browser. A second screenshot<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVh6y.jpg)</sup> from the *Default App Manager* app may be helpful to understand this part:

[image: Default App Manager]

Comment: AD1: Is there **no other way** to reset this apart from third party apps?

Comment: AD2: But sometimes I get asked to select a browser, but sometimes browser+youtube? What happens in the second case if I set browser as always when an app asked me and only presented browsers? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I guess I get what you mean -- and maybe I wasn't clear enough with my explanation: If you select an `.html` file, it might ask you only for a browser. In this case, your selection will be remembered for `.html` files, regardless of from where you called it. Some Flash stuff (e.g. a Youtube link) might ask for browser+youtube -- again, your selection would be remembered for this special "file type" -- but not for `.html` (so in that case, you should be asked again when encountering an `.html`). Hard to explain in words -- I hope I made it this time?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I just didn't know that this is related to file type. It makes perfect sense now. I can see myself selecting some "always" from now on. :)

Comment: At least it is revertable, in case of an error. Besides: It automatically reverts if you update/re-install the affected app (it does so in Gingerbread at least). Besides: If this solves your issue, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

On the Kindle Fire (Gingerbread), I go into Settings > Applications > Third Party Applications and select Dolphin Browser, my usual default browser.  There is a Clear Defaults button on Dolphin's page.  That button un-defaults my browser and restores the question.

I would expect you'd have to do something similar - use system-settings for a given application - to undo it's default-ness.

Comment: Thanks but... Gingerbread is a completely diff OS than ICS or JB (which could at least be considered very similar to some extent). And second, you're talking about Kindle Fire which is an Android but I think we agree that of all the companies that skin Android Fire is the most changed OS. Long(er) story short: **No such setting on my Galaxy Nexus with JB**.